# Need clarification on the Users execution for the Distributed Testing

Tags: jmeter

It might be a  silly question, but I need clarification before requesting for JMeter Infrastructure.

Here is what I understood for the below example scenario.

Master Machine --1; 2 Slave Machines; Total No.Of users 10;Test Duration :5 Mins

So what I have understood and noticed is, If I have executed the test with ONE slave Machine generates 30 Samples. If i have executed the test with 2 Slave machines it generates 60 Samples which i understand as per JMeter Distributed test design.But my only question is test executed for 20 Users?

Please clarify!

Thanks,
Rajani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If the test plan is configured to run with 10 users & if you run that in 2 slave machines, then it runs for 20 users in total (10 users / slave)

> Note: The same test plan is run by all the servers. JMeter does not distribute the load between servers, each runs the full test plan. So if you set 1000 Threads and have 6 JMeter server, you end up injecting 6000 Threads.

[ http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html ]

You do NOT have to move the testplan (.jmx) to the slaves explicitly and It is done automatically which is good. But if the test is referring to any file for test data (say .csv for CSV dataset config) - you need to move those files to all the slaves yourself. JMeter will not do that and the test might fail in the slaves when the file is not present.

Comment: Got it Vinoth! The other part I have hands on!